# getting current user name in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to get the current authenticated username in my razor view page, so I use

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
      <p>Name is @User.Identity.Name</p>
}
```

but @User.Identity.Name always shows the id of the user.

Answer (score 10):

Try this (MVC):

```
@{ var userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; }
```